# Slow performance of POS tagging. Can I do some kind of pre-warming?

Tags: python, nltk

I am using NLTK to POS-tag hundereds of tweets in a web request. As you know, Django instantiates a request handler for each request.

I noticed this: for a request (~200 tweets), the first tweet needs ~18 seconds to tag, while all subsequent tweets need ~120 milliseconds to tag. What can I do to speed up the process?

Can I do a "pre-warming request" so that the module data is already loaded for each request?

```
class MyRequestHandler(BaseHandler):
    def read(self, request): #this runs for a GET request
        #...in a loop:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize( tweet)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag( tokens)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Django code: Django doesn't use `Handler` except in some deep internals. Is it AppEngine's webapp, perhaps?

Comment: Prime it with a bogus request on start-up? Sounds ti me like it works exactly as it should, unless you get a timeout for the long first request.

Comment: @tripleee the 18-second delay happens for first tweet of **each** request

Comment: An idea: (you can verify this through profiling) most of the time is probably taken on "warmup" code of NLTK. Maybe you could hold some NLTK-using class as a global variable, which will stay "warm"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Those first 18 seconds are the POS tagger being unpickled from disk into RAM. If you want to get around this, load the tagger yourself outside of a request function.

```
import nltk.data, nltk.tag
tagger = nltk.data.load(nltk.tag._POS_TAGGER)
```

And then replace `nltk.pos_tag` with `tagger.tag`.
The tradeoff is that app startup will now take +18seconds.

Comment: Use NLTK 3.1 _POS_TAGGER no longer exists, I need to revert to 3.0.1

Answer (score 19):

As stated previously, NLTK unpickles every time is you use the standard pos_tag method. For NLTK 3.1, assuming you're happy with the NLTK's default tagger (PerceptronTagger) then the following method works for me:

First load the tagger:

```
from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
tagger = PerceptronTagger()
```

Then, every time you need to tag a bit of text:

```
tagset = None
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize('the mat sat on the cat')
tags = nltk.tag._pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)
```

This basically bypasses the main method. Speeded things up hundred of times for me. I assume the same method works for any of the taggers.

Comment: `tagger.tag(tokens)` should be sufficient instead of `nltk.tag._pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger)`

Answer (score 5):

nltk's POS tagger is really slow:

For me I can do 13739 tweets in 243 seconds:

1. sent_tokenize 1.06190705299
2. word_tokenize 4.86865639687
3. pos_tag 233.487122536
4. chunker 3.05982065201

See http://honnibal.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/a-good-part-of-speechpos-tagger-in-about-200-lines-of-python/
but to summarize:

```
Tagger     | Accuracy | Time (130k words)
-----------+----------+------------------
CyGreedyAP |    97.1% | 4s
NLTK       |    94.0% | 3m56s
Pattern    |    93.5% | 26s
PyGreedyAP |    96.8% | 12s
```