# POS tagging in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to find out the parts of speech in a particular sentence. I tried to do it using the code given below

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
import nltk.data
a=raw_input()
text = word_tokenize(a)
pairs=nltk.pos_tag(text)
print pairs
```

But it always shows 'Delete' as JJ(adjective) where it is supposed to be Verb.
How can I improve the code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you can ever expect high precision for sentence fragments, but for a start, you would probably need to collect a corpus of correctly tagged sentence fragments to train a new model on. The one you are using was made for analyzing complete sentences in running text.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610076/slow-performance-of-pos-tagging-can-i-do-some-kind-of-pre-warming

Answer (score 0):

First you should get a corpus of correctly tagged sentences (as suggested above). Just augmenting some of the corpora in your nltk_data folder may already be useful. To train your own tagger from this, see: http://nltk-trainer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/train_tagger.html