# How to print out tags in python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

If I have a string such as this:

```
text = "They refuse to permit us."

txt = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

With this if I print POS tags; `nltk.pos_tag(txt)` I get

> [('They','PRP'), ('refuse', 'VBP'), ('to', 'TO'), ('permit', 'VB'), ('us', 'PRP')]

How can I print out only this:

> ['PRP', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a list of tuples, you should iterate through it to get only the second element of each tuple.

```
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(txt)
>>> tags =  [ e[1] for e in tagged]
>>> tags
['PRP', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP']
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Unpacking a list / tuple of pairs into two lists / tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558908/unpacking-a-list-tuple-of-pairs-into-two-lists-tuples)

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> text = "They refuse to permit us."
>>> tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))
>>> tokens, pos = zip(*tagged_text)
>>> pos
('PRP', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP', '.')
```

Possibly at some point you will find the POS tagger is slow and you will need to do this (see [Slow performance of POS tagging. Can I do some kind of pre-warming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610076/slow-performance-of-pos-tagging-can-i-do-some-kind-of-pre-warming)):

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tag import PerceptronTagger
>>> tagger = PerceptronTagger()
>>> text = "They refuse to permit us."
>>> tagged_text = tagger.tag(word_tokenize(text))
>>> tokens, pos = zip(*tagged_text)
>>> pos
('PRP', 'VBP', 'TO', 'VB', 'PRP', '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **iterate** like -

```
print [x[1] for x in nltk.pos_tag(txt)]
```