# How to speed up slow POS tagging?

Tags: python, performance, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

Before you redirect me to another stackoverflow page since I know there are a few questions about speeding up POS tagging, I've already browsed through and sped up my code with the suggestions here: [Slow performance of POS tagging. Can I do some kind of pre-warming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610076/slow-performance-of-pos-tagging-can-i-do-some-kind-of-pre-warming?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm using Python 3.6. I have lists containing ~100,000 words that have been tokenized using nltk. These are pretty hefty lists so I know that tagging all of these words will inherently take some amount of time. I've loaded the tagger outside, as follows:

```
def tag_wordList(tokenizedWordList):       
    from nltk.tag.perceptron import PerceptronTagger
    tagger=PerceptronTagger() # load outside

    for words in tokenizedWordList:
         taggedList = tagger.tag(tokenizedWordList) # add POS to words

    return taggedList
```

Taking this step has sped things up a significant amount, but to get through 100,000+ words, it's still taking over 1.5 hours (and it's still running). The code works fine on a smaller set of data. I believe I tried converting the list to a set at one point without much improvement, though I'm going to try again for good measure. Anyone have any other tips for improving efficiency?

Comment: I highly recommend spacy. It will be as accurate as NLTK and way faster: https://spacy.io/docs/api/

Comment: wait, why do you have a for loop if you are passing the full list to `tagger.tag` anyway.

Comment: @entrophy good catch! i didn't notice until now and that fixed it. thanks!

Comment: @mbatchkarov thanks! my code's working now but i'm definitely going to look into spacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's really your tagging code, you are tagging each ten-word sentence ten times before you go to the next one. Understand how your tools work before you complain that they are too slow.

You can get a further speedup by calling `pos_tag_sents()` on your full list of word-tokenized sentences, instead of launching it separately for each sentence (even just once).

```
tagged_sents = nltk.pos_tag_sents(tokenized_sentences)
```

Comment: Just realized that error in my code. Appreciate the tip